# % padding based on the parent element content's width?

Tags: html, css, padding

I read that if you set padding with % value, it is based on the parent element’s width.

But when I tried it it wasn't exactly true.
I had this parent element with following styling:

```
.player {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 100px 50px;
width: 414px;
max-width: 100%;
```

And the child:

```
.song-img { padding-top: 100%; }
```

And the child's top padding was 314px.

Sooo, I assume that this happened because of the parent's left and right paddings and because its box-sizing is border-box.

Does this mean that the percentage-based padding is based on the parent element CONTENT's width instead of just the width?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: because the child can only span on the 314px left .;) it uses the avalaible width . if on absolute position , padding won'matter anymore.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I'm not sure I understand. I set the padding-top and there was no height set, that could limit it.

Comment: padding-top:100% equals 100% of the width avalaible where that element stands ;) not very intuitive indeed

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Omg, I wouldn't have thought of that! Thank you. So it is like it's based on parent content's width? Without padding etc.?